# probability that he is NOT killed in $20$ years

Tags: probability

### Question

> $\text{suppose that the probability of being killed in a single flight is 
>  }P_{c}=\frac{10^{-6}}{4} \text{based}$
>   $\text{ on available statistics. Assume that different flights are independent. If a businessman}$ $\text{takes 20 flights per year, what is the probability that he is killed in a plane crash within the}$ $\text{next 20 years? (Let's assume that he will not die because of another }$
>   $\text{reason within the next 20 years.)}?$

### My Approach

> $$\text{probability of NOT  being killed in a single flight is 
>  }P_{c}=1-\frac{10^{-6}}{4}$$

There are $20$ flights per year .so Probability that he will not be dying in a year
$$=\left(1-\frac{10^{-6}}{4}\right)^{20}$$

> probability that he is killed in a plane crash within the next $20$ years=probability that he is NOT killed in $20$ years and will be dying in next upcoming $20$years.
>   $$\left(\left(1-\frac{10^{-6}}{4}\right)^{20}\right)^{20} \times \left(\frac{10^{-6}}{4}\right)^{20}$$

Am i correct?
Bit confused.please help me
Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you don't want $P_c = \dfrac{10^{-6}}{4}$?  Because $\dfrac{10^6}{4} = 250,000$ is awfully big for a probability.  Cheers!

Comment: Appology! editing ! Thanks! :)

Comment: Where does that last factor of $\left(\frac{10^{-6}}{4}\right)^{20}$ come from?  You were doing fine up to that point.

Comment: In $20$ years, he takes $20 \times 20 = 400$ flights.  What are his odds of surviving $400$ flights?  His probability of dying is $1$ minus that.  (Actually, these numbers are small enough that you can essentially just multiply his probability of dying on any single flight by $400$.)

Comment: thanks all! @saulspatz actually i added last factor from the fact that he will surive first $20$ year and then die ..last factor i multiplied it with a probability of dying ..which indeed is wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The total number of flights that he will take during the next $20$ years is $N=20\times20=400$.

Let $p_s$ be the probability that he survives a given single flight. Then we have
$$p_s=1-p_c$$
Since these flights are independent, the probability that he will survive all $N=400$ flights is $$P(\mbox{Survive N flights })=p_s\times p_s\times......\times p_s=p_s^{N}=(1-p_c)^N$$Let $A$ be the event that the businessman is killed in a plane crash within the next $20$ years. Then$$P(A)=1-(1-p_c)^N=9.9995\times10^{-5}\approx \dfrac{1}{10000}$$

Comment: See [my approach](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2861611/571724) to this problem. I think both these methods achieve the same answer, but how can we prove the similarity of the 2 formulas?

Answer (score 1):

There is another approach to this problem.
Consider $P(n)$ be the probability that the businessman dies in his $n$th flight.
 $p_c$ is the probability of the person being killed in any flight.
Now, $P(i) = {(1-p_c)}^{i-1} \dot p_c$ i.e. he survived $i-1$ flights and died in $i$th flight.

He will take total $20 \times 20$ flights in 20 years. The probability that he will die in any of these flights is $\sum_{i=1}^{20 \times 20}{P(i)}$.

Therefore, the required probability is $1 - \sum_{i=1}^{20 \times 20}{P(i)}$

Comment: (+1) for alternative approach. The difference is that you took that he dies for $n^{th}$ flight but I took that he survives for all $400$